# Desktop remote control on *Nokia 5800*

Tags: realvnc

I'm trying to remote desktop my laptop and Nokia 5800 with VNC+. I've installed VNC+ on my phone and RealVNC on my laptop but I can't get it to work. It keeps saying "connecting" and then stop (on my phone).

If you any of you guys use a Nokia 5800, please help me, I want to be able to control/see my laptop screen on my phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say what OS is running on your laptop but, in Windows at least, most laptops will have the firewall switched on automatically which will block incoming VNC connections by default.

Try temporarily switching off the Windows firewall to see if that helps, if it does switch the firewall back on and allow an exception in the firewall settings for RealVNC.

Can't really give you more precise instructions without knowing which OS your laptop is running and whether or not you have any 3rd party security software running on it (ie "internet security suite" type software).

Comment: I'm using Windows 7 on my laptop. When i disable firewall, it works. Thanks for helping.